# find files modified in an interval on unix

Tags: unix, find, options

I am on linux and have tried to figure out the find command for a while to be able to list the directories modified in a 24 hour period a certain number of days ago, but I can't get it to work. Among other things I have tried:

`find -type d -mtime +1 -mtime -2`

But it returns 0 matches, while `find -type d -mtime +1` gives 16721 matches and `find -type d -mtime -2` gives 120 matches. I should get around 50-60 matches.

I have also tried the `-a` option for `AND` in between but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments for the `-mtime` option to find are a little counter-intuitive.  Basically, what you're asking for there is "show me everything that's older than two days ago, and younger than two days ago"... the '+' option is a little wonky (from `find`(1)):

> When find figures out how many 24-hour periods ago the file was last accessed, any fractional  part  is ignored, so to match -atime +1, a file has to have been accessed at least two days ago.

For a single day range, you can just use `-mtime 2`, otherwise I suggest going to using `-mmin` and a bit of shell arithmetic to get where you want to go.

Comment: Ah just not using either + or - seem to be that I want.

Comment: +1 - I remember wrestling with that for several hours before find would finally do what I wanted it to.

Comment: Yeah, the find manpage is only for people who can *truly* write "detail oriented" in their CV.  Took me years to really grok it.

Comment: Also, be aware that you can do `-mtime 0` (the current 24-hour period) and `-mtime 0` (more than 24 hours ago) and even `-mtime -0` (future-dated).

Comment: I think you meant `-mtime +0` for that second one...

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a script:

```
STARTTIMEFILE=`mktemp` || exit 1
touch -d '2009-10-01 00:00' "$STARTTIMEFILE" || exit 1

ENDTIMEFILE=`mktemp` || exit 1
touch -d '2009-11-01 00:00' "$ENDTIMEFILE" || exit 1

find . -newer "$STARTTIMEFILE" -and -not -newer "$ENDTIMEFILE" -ls

rm -f "$STARTTIMEFILE" "$ENDTIMEFILE"
```

Much easier to understand than `-mtime`.