# Linux - A more fine grained -mtime for find?

Tags: linux, filesystems, files, find

`find` is a great tool for finding files. It has the option to find files that were modified in the last X days with `-mtime`. However I'd like something more fine grained than that. I want to be able to find files that were modified in the last 2 hours. Is there some way to make find (or some other similar tool) do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

man find

-mmin

File's data was last modified n minutes ago.

Comment: also see Tometzsk'y answer to http://serverfault.com/questions/88222/find-files-modified-in-an-interval-on-unix

Comment: to be more verbose, find . -mmin -120 will find all files with an mtime within the past 2 hours

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to Paul Brewer's (best) answer: `-newer`.  It essentially finds anything newer than a file.  So you can use touch to create a timestamp for a file in the past, then see what's newer than that.

```
touch -t 201002160900 timestamp
find . -newer timestamp
```

Comment: This trick is great when you need to find stuff modified by running a command (`touch timestamp && (some command) && find ...`)